# Compile an executable that can be run with a double click

Tags: gcc

When you compile a file with GCC it generates an executable with the `application/x-sharedlib` mime type. This is recognized as not executable by the file manager. So how do I change it to `application/x-executable`??

```
gcc hello-world.c
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executable binaries labelled as shared library files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604819/executable-binaries-labelled-as-shared-library-files)

Comment: ... as a workaround, you can build the executable with `-fno-pic` / `-no-pie` iirc

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the command you use to compile the program.